# Unable to cast object of type 'AllProjects_Result' to type 'Project'

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i found many article and i make this code

i have this error

> Unable to cast object of type 'AllProjects_Result' to type 'Project'.

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GVAllProjects" runat="server" 
   OnRowDataBound="GVAllProjects_RowDataBound"
    OnRowDeleting="GVAllProjects_RowDeleting"
   OnRowEditing="GVAllProjects_RowEditing"
   OnRowUpdating="GVAllProjects_RowUpdating"
   AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" DataKeyNames="ID">
    <Columns>
    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
           <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblProID" Visible="false" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID")%>' />
                                                    
                                     </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="المشروعات" ItemStyle-Width="150" >
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblProjectName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectName")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtProjectName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="الموقع" ItemStyle-Width="150">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDistrictName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DistrictName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDistrictName" runat="server">
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valDistrictName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlDistrictName"
                                                        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="DistrictName is required." ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True"
                                                        ValidationGroup="editGrp">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDistrictNameNew" runat="server">
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valDistrictNameNew" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlDistrictNameNew"
                                                        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="DistrictName is required." ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True"
                                                        ValidationGroup="newGrp">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="المساحات" ItemStyle-Width="150">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblAreas" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Areas")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAreas" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Areas") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="نظام السداد" ItemStyle-Width="150">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblPaymentSystem" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PaymentSystem")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPaymentSystem" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PaymentSystem") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="تاريخ الاستلام" ItemStyle-Width="150">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblReceivedDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ReceivedDate", "{0:d}")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgPopup" ImageUrl="~/images/-calendar.png" ImageAlign="Bottom" />
                                                    <ajaxToolkit:calendarextender popupbuttonid="imgPopup" id="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" targetcontrolid="txtEditDate"
                                                        format="MM/dd/yyyy" enabled="true" />
                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                                <FooterTemplate>                                                    
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgPopup" ImageUrl="~/images/-calendar.png" ImageAlign="Bottom" />
                                                    <ajaxToolkit:calendarextender id="CalendarExtender2" runat="server"
                                                        targetcontrolid="txtAddDate" popupbuttonid="imgPopup" enabled="true" format="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="تصنيف العقار" ItemStyle-Width="150">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblClassification" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PropertyClassification")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtClassification" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PropertyClassification") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="صورة المشروع" ItemStyle-Width="150">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <img src='ProjectsImages/<%# Eval("ProjectImage") %>' style="width:120px;height:120px;"  />
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:FileUpload ID="UploadPhoto" runat="server" />
                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="الغرض" ItemStyle-Width="150">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblPurposeName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PurposeName")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPurposeName" runat="server">
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valPurposeName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlPurposeName"
                                                        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="PurposeName is required." ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True"
                                                        ValidationGroup="editGrp">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPurposeNameNew" runat="server">
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valClassificationNew" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlPurposeNameNew"
                                                        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="DistrictName is required." ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True"
                                                        ValidationGroup="newGrp">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="النوع" ItemStyle-Width="150">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblTypes" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TypeName")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTypes" runat="server">
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valTypes" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlTypes"
                                                        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Types is required." ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True"
                                                        ValidationGroup="editGrp">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTypesNew" runat="server">
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valTypesNew" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlTypesNew"
                                                        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Types is required." ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True"
                                                        ValidationGroup="newGrp">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
```

and this is my code :

```
 protected void GVAllProjects_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddlDistrictName = null;
    DropDownList ddlPurposeName = null;
    DropDownList ddlTypes = null;
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {

        ddlDistrictName = e.Row.FindControl("ddlDistrictNameNew") as DropDownList;
        ddlPurposeName = e.Row.FindControl("ddlPurposeNameNew") as DropDownList;
        ddlTypes = e.Row.FindControl("ddlTypesNew") as DropDownList;
    }
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

        ddlDistrictName = e.Row.FindControl("ddlDistrictName") as DropDownList;
        ddlPurposeName = e.Row.FindControl("ddlPurposeName") as DropDownList;
        ddlTypes = e.Row.FindControl("ddlTypes") as DropDownList;
    }
    if (ddlDistrictName != null)
    {
        using (AlamaarRealEstateEntities context = new AlamaarRealEstateEntities())
        {
            ddlDistrictName.DataSource = context.Districts.ToList();
            ddlDistrictName.DataTextField = "DistrictName";
            ddlDistrictName.DataValueField = "ID";
            ddlDistrictName.DataBind();

            ddlPurposeName.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(""));
            ddlPurposeName.DataSource = context.Purposes.ToList();
            ddlPurposeName.DataTextField = "PurposeName";
            ddlPurposeName.DataValueField = "ID";
            ddlPurposeName.DataBind();

            ddlTypes.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(""));

            ddlTypes.DataSource = context.Types.ToList();
            ddlTypes.DataTextField = "TypeName";
            ddlTypes.DataValueField = "ID";
            ddlTypes.DataBind();

        }
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
            {

                ddlDistrictName.SelectedValue = ((Project)(e.Row.DataItem)).DistrictID.ToString(); 
                ddlPurposeName.SelectedValue = ((Project)(e.Row.DataItem)).PurposeID.ToString(); ;
                ddlTypes.SelectedValue = ((Project)(e.Row.DataItem)).TypeID.ToString();
            }

        }
    }
}

 void BindGrid()
{
    using (AlamaarRealEstateEntities context = new AlamaarRealEstateEntities())
    {
        if (context.Projects.Count() > 0)
        {
            GVAllProjects.DataSource = context.AllProjects().ToList();
            GVAllProjects.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            var obj = new List<Project>();
            obj.Add(new Project());
            // Bind the DataTable which contain a blank row to the GridView
            GVAllProjects.DataSource = obj;
            GVAllProjects.DataBind();
            int columnsCount = GVAllProjects.Columns.Count;
            GVAllProjects.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();// clear all the cells in the row
            GVAllProjects.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell()); //add a new blank cell
            GVAllProjects.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = columnsCount; //set the column span to the new added cell

            //You can set the styles here
            GVAllProjects.Rows[0].Cells[0].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            GVAllProjects.Rows[0].Cells[0].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            GVAllProjects.Rows[0].Cells[0].Font.Bold = true;
            //set No Results found to the new added cell
            GVAllProjects.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "NO RESULT FOUND!";
        }

    }
}
```

the error here in this lines :

```
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
            {

                ddlDistrictName.SelectedValue = ((Project)(e.Row.DataItem)).DistrictID.ToString(); 
                ddlPurposeName.SelectedValue = ((Project)(e.Row.DataItem)).PurposeID.ToString(); ;
                ddlTypes.SelectedValue = ((Project)(e.Row.DataItem)).TypeID.ToString();
            }

        }
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to cast `(e.Row.DataItem)` to a `Project` but that returns something which is not of type `Project`

Comment: Ok ,what can i do to solve this error any advice ?

Comment: you have to figure out what the type is in `e.Row.DataItem`

Comment: how ? i do it..

Comment: Use the debugger to see what is the type.

Comment: sorry for not being super helpful. I am busy so I cannot go through your code right now.